# Why is RegExp.test consuming a lot of time in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, internet-explorer

When using jQuery to load HTML into an element, I am seeing very poor performance in IE.  Chrome is not showing any performance problems.  Changing the IE browser mode does not appear to improve the performance.

When running the profiler in IE, I see that most of the time is being spent in the `RegExp.test` function.

HTML:
`<div id="content"></div>`
JavaScript: 
`var htmlString = <div>...Lots and lots of content...</div>`
`$('#content').html(htmlString);`

- jQuery version: 1.9.1
- IE version: 9

Comment: IE<10 has always been known for a slow Javascript engine. I have no proof to backup that `RegExp.test` is "slow" though...

Comment: I solved my problem by placing an empty set of div's at the beginning of the content HTML.  Posting the question in case anyone else experiences this.

Comment: Feel free to post an answer explaining how you solved your problem! It'll help others know that the problem has been solved.

Comment: I will post my full answer as soon as I can.  New user here, just wanted to put out my problem and solution to help others.

Comment: (fn.html() uses multiple `re.test`s internally)

Comment: Alex K. - Yes, jQuery is doing the RegExp.test, not me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When loading a large amount of content, don’t start with an opening tag and end with the closing tag.

Change content to:
`var htmlString = <div></div><div>...Lots and lots of content...</div>`

After researching the problem I found this jQuery bug request that pointed me in the right direction. jQuery Ticket #11456

It appears that for IE compatibility, JavaScript RegExp is used to parse the content that is being loaded. When the content starts with a tag, it tries to find the end tag (or something like that). If the amount of data is large, it can take quite a while to do this parsing. I solved my problem by putting an empty  at the beginning.

Comment: what is "an empty" ?

Answer (score 0):

Updating JQuery will probably help.

- Issue: [html() uses a regular expression that performs badly in IE > 9](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2563)
- Introduced here: [commit in 2012, affecting JQuery >= 1.8.0](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/4cd57d727a075617c8db30dcf69542f66add63fe)

The issue should be fixed for JQuery >= 1.12.0 / 2.2.0